# canvas.todataURL doesn't work on first attempt

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I am trying to draw canvas image from image source. 
This below code sinppet is working fine but in IOS--  iPad-chrome  and mac-safari not working for first time it is working fine from next try. Don't know where I was wrong. Please help me to get rid of this issue.

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasThumbResult");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");    
        var img = document.getElementById("ImagSrc");
        context.drawImage(img, x, y, wi, hi, 0, 0, wi, hi);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        $("#CanvasImg").attr("src", dataURL);
        $("#CanvasImg").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the image to load:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasThumbResult");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");    
    var img = document.getElementById("ImagSrc");
    if (img.complete) {
      draw();
    } else {
      img.onload = function() { draw(); };
    }

    function draw() {
      context.drawImage(img, x, y, wi, hi, 0, 0, wi, hi);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      $("#CanvasImg").attr("src", dataURL);
      $("#CanvasImg").show(); 
    }
```

Comment: setting image source attribute dynamically... img.onload is not firing.. still same issue.